# Intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I wanted to prove that the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite group G is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Can someone enlighten me how is this implication possible:

If an automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ maps every Sylow $p$-subgroup to a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then the image of the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups under $\sigma$ is itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the intersection of all $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$.  If $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup then $N = \cap_{g\in G}gPg^{-1}$.
Thus we have for all $x\in G$ that
$$
xNx^{-1} = \bigcap_{g\in G}(xg)P(xg)^{-1} = \bigcap_{g\in G}gPg^{-1} = N,
$$
so N is normal.

For the question on $\sigma$ see the accepted answer here:

[Intersection of all $p$-Sylow subgroups is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041648/intersection-of-all-p-sylow-subgroups-is-normal)

So in fact, this works and $N$ is a *characteristic subgroup* and in particular normal.

Comment: I already see it now. Thanks!

Comment: $N = \cap_{g\in G}gPg^{-1}$ is by Sylow II, right?